# Hough Transform failed in opencv

Tags: opencv, image-processing

[image]

This is a picture above. I am using opencv to process it and I have tried to use  Hough Transform, but failed. Also, I found that it is so hard to set relative parameters in Hough Transform.

The codes are as following:

```
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>

using namespace cv;
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    Mat srcImg = imread("srccenter.bmp");
    Mat greyImg;
    cvtColor(srcImg, greyImg, COLOR_BGR2GRAY);

    std::vector<cv::Vec3f> circles;

    /// Apply the Hough Transform to find the circles
    HoughCircles(greyImg, circles, CV_HOUGH_GRADIENT, 1, 10, 100, 20, 0,   0);

    /// Draw the circles detected
    for (size_t i = 0; i < circles.size(); i++)
    {
        Point center(cvRound(circles[i][0]), cvRound(circles[i][1]));
        int radius = cvRound(circles[i][2]);
        circle(srcImg, center, 3, Scalar(0, 255, 255), -1);
        circle(srcImg, center, radius, Scalar(0, 255, 0), 1);
    }

    namedWindow("srcImg", WINDOW_NORMAL);
    imshow("srcImg", srcImg);
    waitKey(0);
    return 0;
 }
```

But the result is I can not detect any circle.

How I can detect the inner circle?

Do you have any good ideas?

Comment: did you ever consider to google "circle detection opencv"? come on! there is even an official tutorial on that http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/doc/tutorials/imgproc/imgtrans/hough_circle/hough_circle.html

Comment: I have put up my codes, Please have a look.@Piglet

Comment: why is your min and max radius 0?
make sure you understand what the parameters do and limit the radius to the range you expect your inner circle in.

Comment: Primarily, I want to detect all circles in the picture, so I did not set a limit fog radius. But even so, any circle is detected.@Piglet

Comment: Now the problem is that I cannot detect any circle, let alone the inner circle!@Piglet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change min_dist parameter to zero. This parameter is for minimum distance between detected centers. in your case, centers of the circles are so near.
And Also, you must change param_1, the parameter of the Canny edge detector.

Comment: Your advice is quite useful. As you say, I changed the relative parameters many times and finally realized something about these parameters.@zahra rah